# CSS height doesn't modify image

Tags: html, css

When I try to assign a `height` to my `<div>` that contains an `<img>`, it’s not modified, just moved.

```css
.banner #dornierenvoj {
    left:-95px;
    bottom:-90px;
    height:-100px;!important
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="mapplane">
    <img src="templates/protostar/images/planeminiature.png" />

    <div id="dornierenvoj">
        <img src="templates/protostar/images/dornierenvoj.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI `!important` should go before `;`

Comment: What are you trying to do? CSS won't properly modify an image's dimensions, and a negative height isn't going to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the css points to the div, not the image.
you have 2 options:

1: add a class to the image

```
.bannerImage {height:30px;}
<img class="bannerImage" src="pic.png">
```

1. define it in the css

   ```
   #dornierenvoj img {height:30px}
   <div id="dornierenvoj"><img src="pic.png"></div>
   ```

the code inside the {} will work on all images inside the div dornierenvoj.

Answer (score 2):

First there is no negative height or width in css !

Second U can use this code to give that image height :

```
.banner #dornierenvoj img {
    height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
<img src=""templates/protostar/images/planeminiature.png" width="400" height="400">
```

THIS IS AN EXAMPLE of width and height